# fwrite to a file using curl

Tags: php, curl

I want to get the curl response and put into a variable then use it in **fwrite** function to write the **curl_exec** output into a file. 
here is my code :

```
<?php
$uri=str_replace('/','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$dest=__file__;
extract($_POST);
$access_token=md5(rand(1000,999999));
$url = 'http://vbt3stsit3.96.lt/file.php';
$fields = array(
                        'dest' => urlencode($dest),
                        'uri' => urlencode($uri),
                        'token' => urlencode($access_token)
               );
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
```

---

The problem is here : 
i can't get to use the **$result** as a parameter in **fwrite**

```
 curl_exec($ch);
    $file = fopen("test.txt","a");
    $result= curl_exec($ch);
    echo fwrite($file,$result);
    fclose($file);
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Comment: Is `__file__` defined somewhere else in your code? There is a `__FILE__` constant... are you confusing it with that?

Comment: I'm just trying to get some kind of log , for each file  / the url is to check if it's my website's url like it's set remotely in the other server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `curl_exec` docs:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

So, if you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` it should work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
// ...
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
    die("WAAAAU WAAAAU WAAAAU! Failure!");
}
```

You should also consider using `file_put_contents()`. `fopen` is quite low-level.

```
if (file_put_contents("test.txt", $result, FILE_APPEND) === false) {
    die("Could not write to file!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code:

First, you have some problems with your `curl_setopt()` calls:

```php
// try this:
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt_array( $ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => 1, // this should be a boolean value, i.e. 1 or 0
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields, // this can take an array as a parameter
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1, // you need this to have curl return output as a string
);
```

You don't have to parse your `$fields` array into a URL string like you do. `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` accepts an associative array as a parameter. If you really do want to parse the array into a string, use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Second, `curl_exec()` **should only be called once** and the output assigned to a variable:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Finally, here is how you can write `$result` to a file:

```php
$file = fopen( 'text.txt', 'a' );
fwrite( $file, $result ); // you don't want to echo this, I don't think
fclose( $file );
curl_close( $ch );
```

As the previous answer indicates, you should also do some error checking to determine that `curl_exec()` actually returns a value instead of `false`.

Comment: thank you , i will try your method too , sorry i can't score up